# Vintage VCR PSU: finding circuit breaker

Tags: power-supply, circuit-analysis, pcb-design, circuit-protection

[image: PSU Schematic]

After a grueling 8-hour overhaul of a high end VCR, which included recapping the entire PSU, disassembly to fit the new capstan motor, and cleaning/oiling of the mechanism, got all working fine and while doing the last adjustment (5V voltage) I shorted the PSU and it activated a circuit breaker.

There are 3 test points, TP1 (12V), TP2 (5V) and TP3 (GND). Was so exhausted I shorted TP1 and TP2 - circuit breaker was activated in 1 or 2 seconds and mains to the VCR went off.

Please could you help me find the circuit breaker in the schematic? I can barely read anything, I almost had a heart attack after all the work and having it working great.

Actual pics of PSU:

https://ibb.co/album/hNYOrF

Comment: a higher resolution would be nice. I see a relay near the power input on the left, could that be it?

Comment: I can't find the TPs on the schematic due to poor resolution. A couple of coloured circles to highlight them would be nice. On the bad news side, connecting the 12 V supply to the 5 V logic circuit may have over-volted all the logic chips and something critical may have died.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I also think it may be a relay, see HD pictures of the actual PCB: https://ibb.co/album/hNYOrF

Comment: SysteUse systematic trouble shooting. Treat ALL parts as at mains ACV. | Is there mains at PCB input? after fues? Before common mode choke? After choke? On PTRANS board? Is ther lowvoltage PTRans board voltages? | Is their rectified mains DC after bridge rectifier? On Q1 collector? ... .

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any circuit breakers but there are three fuses. If you look at the schematic you can see three bridge rectifiers. To the left of each of these (on the input side) is a fuse. I can't tell from the low resolution image whether you might have blown just one of these or several...you should check them all.

Having said all of that, if you don't know what a fuse symbol looks like or how to check them on the circuit board then you are entering dangerous territory. The voltages around the fuses could kill you. You might want to leave that part of the repair to someone who is accustomed to working with mains voltages safely.

Comment: There is only one fuse, in the traditional "fuse slotted into the fuse holder", please see pictures: https://ibb.co/album/hNYOrF

Comment: @MusicWorks At a cursory glance, I don't see any fuse in those pictures. Please point out the fuse specifically, and look around for any other fuses--some of them just look like little resistor-like capsules

Comment: Well, the schematics show 3 fuses, one for each of the bridge rectifiers. Perhaps the schematics are for a different device.

Comment: Guys, I an pretty sure I tripped the relay and just need to revert it to the connected position. Any tips?

Comment: If you are "pretty sure" that you "tripped the relay" and no one can even see a relay on the schematic then I think you are working at a mystical level of circuit magic that is beyond my knowledge. Good luck.

Comment: It is in the schematic, I was surprised you missed it the first time...but two times! Is just next to one of the bridge rectifiers you mentioned, and labeled RY1

Comment: RY1 is for a switched **output** receptacle, not for power to the VCR itself.

Comment: Then it must be the diodes in the bridge rectifiers, right?

Comment: No, there is no reason to state that it "must" be the diodes. Have you found all of the fuses yet?

Comment: Yes, I found all three fuses: F51 and F52 are not glass fuses but micro fuses (they look like two-legged transistors) and they both show continuity -like the glass fuse F1. The same tipe of micro fuse is used in CP1 and CP3 (both act as ICP in the circuit), CP1 is fine but CP3 shows NO continuity

Answer (score 0):

I suspect your problem is a blown fuse designated as F1 located near the AC input.

Comment: I took out the fuse and measured for continuity with the multimeter, fuse is not blown.